# How to sync database between local or staging and the live store

Tags: magento2, database, extensions

I am coming from **Wordpress** and the way I sync my database there is by **using a plugin** to pull and push databases **between too environments**, and I was wondering if there is a similar approach with **Magento 2** if not than what is the best way?

Also I want to know what are they tables that I need to change once I pushed or pulled a database. From what I can see I only need to change the links on core_config_data

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a synchronisation tool available on Github that automatically configures your development environment for you

https://github.com/jellesiderius/mage-db-sync/

Answer (score 1):

You can also configure env.php locally to use your "local" domain name & db connection in app/etc/env.php

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/config/config-php.html

like that you "override" the code_config_data value.

it's available since 2.2 and working well.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve what you are after to is to export/copy the latest database and then import it to the old database, this way all your data will be up to date.

You are also correct in saying the only thing that needs to change is in the core_config_data table, the these are the 2 fields relating to the base url (secure & unsecure).

EDIT:

SELECT * from `core_config_data` WHERE `path` = 'web/unsecure/base_url';

SELECT * from `core_config_data` WHERE `path` = 'web/secure/base_url';

Run these commands to find the urls you require and make changes accordingly